# No email response after requesting account deletion

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have been inactive on stack Overflow for 2 years. I am logged in with facebook , so my real name is assocated with my account. I want to completely delete my account and start over. When I try requesting deletion, it says an email got sent to my email account. The problem is that when I try to login yahoo with correct credentials, it wants me to answer a security question which I do not remember(who does?). Due to this I changed my stack exchange username and real name and email.
I believed that in this way , when I required deletion the email would be sent to my new email account, but it didn't. What can I do to completely delete my account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You originally contacted us (well, the first contact I could find from the email associated with your account) yesterday. While we do monitor support for urgent things over the weekend, our support hours are technically during the week - response time is generally about 24 hours - we get about 200 requests every day.

I've removed your account, let us know if you need anything else.